# AJAX crawling scheme & redirects

Tags: seo, google, ajax

I am about to implement Google's AJAX crawling scheme so for every single pretty URL on my site (apart from the homepage) there will be an equivalent ugly one using _escaped_fragment_ .

This means that`www.example.com/#!page1` (pretty URL) would also exist as `www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=page1`

The problem I have is that URLs on my site can be frequently updated so page1 can be renamed page2. In this case page1 will cease to exist and I need to redirect it.

In this case, what would be the best way (in terms of SEO) to redirect page1 to page2?

1. 301 redirect `www.example.com/#!page1` to `www.example.com/#!page1`?
2. 301 redirect `www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=page2` to `http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=page2`
3. Both 1 & 2
4. Other e.g. use JavaScript redirects

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can't server-side redirect from `http://www.example.com/#!page1` to `http://www.example.com/#!page2` because the server doesn't see the fragment ("#!page1"). For AJAX-crawling, you'd need to redirect from the old crawlable URL to the new displayed URL, which will ultimately result in the new crawlable URL being crawled.

So in short: 301 redirect from `http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=page1` to `http://www.example.com/#!page2`